# Question incorrectly closed as duplicate

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

Again, I believe [my question about string concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361063/should-i-use-append-line-or?noredirect=1#comment23441765_16361063) was incorrectly closed as Duplicate.

Why? 
As stated in the comments:

> In fairness, that is definitely not a duplicate question - it focuses on why StringBuilder is faster than separate string concatenations, not on this specific question on why the alternative syntax also works on StringBuilder and whether the two are functionally identical. Also, there's some stuff in that other topic that isn't entirely true. In a well-prepared case multiple concatenations will never outperform StringBuilder, if you select it's initial capacity correctly with the alternative constructor.

On the top of my question I can read:

[image]

And then go see the *duplicate* question and read:

> I know the obvious performance advantage to using the StringBuilder is in C#

Well I don't know them and it's kind of the point of my question. Can someone take a few seconds to look at it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers for the duplicate question answers your question, even if the two questions are slightly different.

Your question is whether you should use string concatenation or a stringbuilder, when, and why, and that's *exactly* what the answers in the other questions answer.  The OP of that other question is asking for something more in depth, yes, but the answers don't assume much in the way of previous knowledge of the subject on the reader.

Since the answers answer your question, even though the questions are a bit different, closing it as a duplicate is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Note the text:

> This question already has an answer here:

And note the beginning of the highest upvoted and accepted answer:

> Short answer: StringBuilder is appropriate in cases where...

And your question, for reference:

> Should I use append line or += [duplicate]

This is correct.

Now that being said, I don't actually know what to do about the original question.  I edited its title to more precisely reflect the question being asked.  Then it ends with "As a sidenote..." which is frowned upon and puts it in NARQ territory.  But then the accepted answer doesn't answer the question at all and answers *your* question.  Honestly the best thing to do is probably heavily revise the question to match the accepted answer, so if someone tries to ask the question's actual question they don't refer to this one, which has no answer.

Comment: The actual body of the question says *"Should I use AppendLine or += **and why**"*, while the linked question is only *"Does StringBuilder use more memory than String concatenation?"*, which addresses one factor of when you should use StringBuilder over +=. Its possible the OP is looking for other reasons than just memory usage.

Comment: @Rachel it seems like they don't understand what I meant. But it's ok that's how it works around here. It looks like a duplicate so it is treated as so.